# Error in date format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

`<input type='time' class='form-control' value='{{Doctor.Open_time_to | date:"HH:mm:ss"}}' data-ng-model='Doctor.Open_time_to' required>`

At this place is is giveing an exception that

does not conform to the required format.  The format is "HH:mm", "HH:mm:ss" or "HH:mm:ss.SSS" where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999.

Comment: what Ujjwal kaushik saying is right i think

Comment: You have a string, not a date. You need to convert it to a Date object.

Comment: Yes we can do this with out using 3rd party so why use 3rd party Yes Ujjwal is saying is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model need  to be a Date object, so Use this

```
$scope.your_date_model = new Date(your_date_variable);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

post your code, it's hard to understand.
Your date obj is some how damaged, r u using pure JS? jQuery? 
if your not using *"Moment.js"*, I strongly recommend you to add it to tour project, for all your date object:
     http://momentjs.com/